# Combine database users/login for two sites- different directories- Joomla 3.0 / Jomsocial 3.0

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have two Joomla 3.0 sites installed on the same hosting account, each in their own directory on their own database. Both are subdomains of the same domain. The are hosted with Bluehost shared hosting at the moment, but I will be upgrading to VPS hosting once I go live.

Hosting environemnt:

Apache version  2.2.25
PHP version 5.4.17
MySQL version   5.5.33-log
Architecture    x86_64
Operating system    linux

Site #1:
subdomain1.domain.com
- is an online magazine with login/registration and ability to comment on articles. I am using the Zoo component for content articles rather than the Joomla default.I am also using the JFBConnect component and SCLogin module.

Site #2
subdomain2.domain.com
- is an installation of Jomsocial 3.0 with login/registration only, also using the FBConnect component and SCLogin module.

Both are using the same responsive Yootheme warp framework template. I intentionally installed them in different directories under the theory that if one were to malfunction, at least the other would be viable in the interim.

My question(s):

Is it possible for users to login and register just once in order to be recognized by both sites/databases and have full use of all functions in both?

Is my installation of Jomsocial on a separate directory the best course of action, given my rationale?

Are there any other considerations to the above scenaio that I might have overlooked?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I have to say it's probably not the best method you've chosen here.

It's not so much the files that you have to worry about, it's the database as all data is stored here.  I would personally suggest having you're main site on the main domain and taking daily backups of the database and a backup of the folder/files every time you, for example, install an extension which adds new files and folders..

If something goes wrong, simply uploads the backup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using jFusion. The warp framework, jomsocial etc has zero relevance. http://www.jfusion.org

That said, your assumptions for implementing this method for having a viable site available are seriously flawed.